# Not enough permissions to create backup

Tags: magento-1.9

I have to do some Backup and now magento 1.9 display this message in local server `Not enough permissions to create backup.`
What can i do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is caused by Mage not having the permission to touch all files within it's directory.

I would suggest checking out the folders permissions to see what one(s) may be causing the issue. A quick google also shows a quick debugging process. I will copy it here for you.

Go to Configuration - Advanced - Developer and enable logs.
Next copy

```
lib/Mage/Backup/Filesystem/Helper.php
```

into

```
app/code/local/Mage/Backup/Filesystem/Helper.php (create these folders)
```

now find

```
if (($infoOptions & self::INFO_READABLE) && !$item->isReadable()) {    $info['readable'] = false;}
```

and change it to

```
if (($infoOptions & self::INFO_READABLE) && !$item->isReadable()) {    Mage::log($item->getPathname(), null, 'backup_not_readable_files.log');    $info['readable'] = false;}
```

Now clear the cache if it isn't disabled and rerun the backup process. Once completed and the error occurs read

```
/var/log/ for a file named backup_not_readable_files.log
```

This will tell you the information you need to know.

Comment: For me, this revealed the error `DEBUG (7)` for the `mage` executable file in Magento's root directory. I set permissions to `777` while backing up and this resolved the problem. I then set them back to `700` for good measure.

Answer (score 1):

The Best Thing, in the Var root of Magento, Look for file named:   Core.php, you'll find the permission 000, log in from your hosting server, and edit the file permission from 000 to 644, it's doing perfect with me after doing the upper instructions.

At the end, the error is `Need a permission for file named Cron.php`

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem, run this command in terminal from Magento root:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
```

If backups folder exists but Magento cannot create the backup, from within var folder run this command:

```
sudo chmod 777 backups/
```

Explanation: To work correctly, all folders within var folder should have permissions set to 777. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244596/what-permissions-are-needed-to-run-magento/9304264#9304264) is a more detailed explanation

Comment: which is depending on the environment a pretty big security issue, you should never just set whole directories to 777